# jQuery On function for future elements?

Tags: jquery

```
$("#dataTable tbody").on("click", "tr", function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

is this syntax is for tr's which are already on the Page ?

and if not , What is the syntax for future tr's  elements ?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

For future elements inside `#dataTable tbody`, your code should work. To delegate the click all the way up to the document, allowing the same handler for future `<tr>` anywhere on the page, try:

```
$(document).on("click", "tr", function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: so what youre saying is that the "on" is also for current and future dom ?

Comment: Yes, as long as the inserted element is inside the element that bound the event.

Comment: Exactly what i needed. I love you

Comment: i upvoted this. but is there a way i can delegate click to more than one element same function

Comment: Thanks helped with my colege homework very much!!!

Answer (score 5):

Adding to Davids accepted answer, you can also use this solution to bind multiple events to a selector as well as all future matching elements.

For example an input element.

```
$(document).on({
    focus:function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    },
    blur: function(){
        alert($(this).val());
    }
}, 'input[type=text]');
```

Answer (score 1):

This will handle all `<tr>`s, no matter when they were created, but only within the currently-existing `#dataTable tbody`.
It's equivalent to `.delegate`.

Comment: So there is no difference anymore between "already in dom" vs "will be in dom" ?

Comment: There are still differences but delegate(), live() and on() can handle both.

Comment: @Stefan since 1.7 I should not use live anymore and delegate is like on.... so there is no difference anymore ......right?

Comment: You´re right, you shouldn´t use `live()` since 1.7 but `delegate()` and `on()` can handle a modified DOM which `click()` doesn´t.

Comment: @RoyiNamir there is a difference. Using syntax like `$('.container elem').on('click', function(){})` is only for current elements. Using syntax like `$('.container').on('click', 'elem', function(){})` handles future elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You have to use jQuery'S [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for future elements</strike>

Wrong, as this is jQuery 1.7 (and i was to fast in posting my answer).

`.on()` works for all (future) elements.

Comment: It's deprecated in 1.7 instead you have [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Well, thats right, have just seen the "deprecated" on jQuery site

Answer (score 0):

From [api.jquery.com/on/](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected set
>   of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method
>   provides all functionality required for attaching event handlers. For
>   help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see .bind(),
>   .delegate(), and .live(). To remove events bound with .on(), see
>   .off(). To attach an event that runs only once and then removes
>   itself, see .one()

and from [api.jquery.com/live/](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to
>   attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use
>   .delegate() in preference to .live().